# Laravel read value of array inside of array

Tags: laravel

I diedump this array and there is a number inside data array

```
^ array:1 [▼
  "data" => array:15 [▼
    0 => array:15 [▼
      "product_name" => "MOBILELEGEND - 86 Diamond"
      "category" => "Games"
      "brand" => "MOBILE LEGEND"
      "type" => "Umum"
      "seller_name" => "PT***"
      "price" => 19800
      "buyer_sku_code" => "ML86"
      "buyer_product_status" => true
      "seller_product_status" => true
      "unlimited_stock" => true
      "stock" => 0
      "multi" => true
      "start_cut_off" => "23:30"
      "end_cut_off" => "0:20"
      "desc" => "no pelanggan = gabungan antara user_id dan zone_id"
    ]
    1 => array:15 [▶]
    2 => array:15 [▶]
  ]
]
```

How can I foreach the value inside the number? the number I mean is 0,1,2

Comment: This is nothing to do with Laravel, and not even PHP. This is an array, and looping through an array is what you asked, which is fine. But if you needed asking this question, I sincerely suggest you learn the basics of a programing language (in this case PHP would be better) and then start working with Laravel or anything complex. Otherwise, you will need to ask millions of question and you can't learn anything.

Comment: isn't asking is learning right? There is a proverb in my country, "If you are shy of asking questions, you will get lost in your way". But thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Asking is not a problem. And it's your choise how you will try learning. I'm just saying that before knowing the fundamentals, asking won't help you.

Comment: Yeah you know, asking is my second way for learning while trying to solve the problem by my self in case you can't find or solve it by your self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested foreach to loop through the multidimensional array you have.

let your array be called `$arr` for example

```
// $arr = [ 'data' => [ ['name' => 'lorem'], ... ]];

foreach ($arr['data'] as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        // Do whatever you need here...
    }
}
```